# Stop iframe redirect/opening mobile safari trigger io

Tags: mobile, iframe, trigger.io

I want to host an iframe as an app, it works fine on android, the in-app browser allows me to handle all urls from within the app, but the same iframe on iOS always opens clicked links in safari, is there a work around to this?

Comment: This is probably an iOS UIWebview property that the trigger.io team needs to set.

Comment: Hi Eoin, thanks for letting us know about this - we're looking into it and will get back to you.

Comment: @JamesBrady thats awesome! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with iFrames that I was originally using to do Cross-domain requests when I originally wrote my app. I found that Safari kept launching each time I attempted to load content into the iFrame in order to complete my request. I had to swap it out for forge.request.ajax in the end to prevent this from happening.

Might not be the same issue as you are experiencing but hopefully it may steer you in the right direction as to why it is happening.